# TreeView inside ScrollWindow prints warning

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Spent 2 days to solve this, so I find this very useful.

I am followed by [this GTKmm tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en), added Gtk::TreeView in Gtk::ScrolledWindow but when I am adding more rows it shows messages like this:

> (GUI:25948): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to gtkmm__GtkWindow
>   0x55ad53e44500 without calling
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the
>   size to allocate?

How to remove warnings? Its annoying too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have `ExampleWindow` class with this childs

```
Gtk::ScrolledWindow m_ScrolledWindow;
Gtk::TreeView m_TreeView;
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> m_refTreeModel;
```

Inside your `ExampleWindow()` constructor replace this:

```
m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC, Gtk::POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
```

with:

```
m_ScrolledWindow.set_policy(Gtk::POLICY_ALWAYS, Gtk::POLICY_ALWAYS);
m_ScrolledWindow.set_resize_mode(Gtk::ResizeMode::RESIZE_IMMEDIATE);
```

I've replaced `POLICY_AUTOMATIC` with `POLICY_ALWAYS` because of `SIGSEGV` in `/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0`